# iOS. Different static variables with the same name in multiple classes?

Tags: ios, static, non-static

I need something like this:

.h files:

```
@interface A : UIViewController
- (void)setCount:(int)c;
- (int)getCount;
@end

@interface B : A
@end

@interface C : A
@end
```

.m files

```
@implementation A
- (void)setCount:(int)c {...}
- (int)getCount {...}
@end

@implementation B
static int count = -1;
@end

@implementation C
static int count = -1;
@end
```

But this code wouldn't work while `getCount` and `setCount:` are not implemented in classes B and C. The problems:

- implementing of these 2 methods in each class is not very appropriate because there are a lot of classes in my application;
- I can't declare a static variable inside class A because it will be the same for each subclass
- the variable should be static because I need to store its value before alloc/dealloc calls

Are there any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: gnasher has explained the facts, but generally just do not use static variables, unless you're very advanced.  if you genuinely need a "global", perhaps in game programming, learn to use singletons.

Comment: What exactly wouldn't work in your code? `static int count = -1;` This?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one static object with a given name in each source file, or inside each scope. @implementation doesn't matter. So if your code is in one source file, it's illegal. If the @implementations are in two different source files, you are fine. If the static variables are in different scopes you are fine. For example

```
- (NSInteger)countBools:(BOOL)aBool
{
    if (aBool)
    {
        static NSInteger count;
        return ++count;
    }
    else
    {
        static NSInteger count;
        return ++count;
    }
}
```

will work just fine, returning one counter that increases each time you call the method with YES, and another counter that increases each time you call the method with NO.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, you have inspired me for a better solution. I can't avoid declaring of a static variable inside each class but I can make this process much more simpler.

I declare a `#define` with a static variable declaration inside the `A.h` and use it in each subclass with a single line only. It is not very beautiful but I am also free to declare all the methods linked with this variable (if I'll need them) in a simple way.